# Template engine for Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, templates, wicket, freemarker

Can you recommend a template engine for GAE?
I like [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org), but it carries a lot of server-side state, which is something that is not very compatible with the GAE approach.

Is [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net) supported on GAE?

**EDIT**

My primary requirements for the template engine are:

- Ease of development (separation of logic and design)
- Intuitive syntax, since users may customize some templates
- Fast, lightweight

Comment: http://freemarker.blogspot.com/2010/02/freemarker-on-google-app-engine.html seems to indicate that FreeMarker is not (currently) supported in Java App Engine

Comment: See http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava for a list of frameworks which will run in Java App Engine.

Comment: What exactly are your requirements? JSP is available out of the box for GAE/J.

Comment: freemarker is available for GAE now
http://freemarker.blogspot.com/2010/02/freemarker-on-google-app-engine.html

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/freemarker/freemarker-gae/

Comment: "closed as not constructive"? Give me a break! +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [Play framework](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/templates). It has [support for GAE](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/gae) and is completely [stateless server-side](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/guide5#aHowdowemanagethestatea).

Comment: Looks very impressive!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am using FreeMarker on GAE quite successfully.  I have it handling all of the html files with welcome-file directory handling working fine.  For more information, see [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127610/freemarker-cannot-handle-request-for-on-google-app-engine/4134099#4134099).  I have my web.xml file and other details there.

Comment: I keep having an issue with my freemarker and eclipse , It doesn't seem to deploy the .ftl file to gae when i run mvn appengine:deploy , Please how did you get passed this ?.

Comment: Sorry I've not used GAE for a while.  I think I made the freemarker handler render all HTML files by default @I.Tyger.

Answer (score 1):

Rythm is a Strong typed Java template engine using [Razor](http://razorengine.codeplex.com) like syntax with high performance (2 to 3 times faster than Velocity and FM). It provides a very lightweight way to do String interpolation:

```
String result = Rythm.render("hello @who!", "world");
```

This simplicity makes Rythm a good replacement for `String.format()` in many cases. Please be noted that `Rythm.render` is 2x faster than `String.format`

For comprehensive template you can use the same interface to pass in the file name:

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("who", "world");
...
String result = Rythm.render("myTemplate.html", args);
```

Rythm has very rich feature set including java flow control (if-else, for loop, collection iteration), template inheritance, external and internal tags creation and invocation, caching, Java method extension, space compact, html escape etc. Most of the features are demonstrated at http://play-rythm-demo.appspot.com/. (And Yes, the demo is written with Play!Framework plus Rythm template engine and it is running on GAE!)

There is Play!Framework plugin created on Rythm engine, you can find documentation on how to use Rythm from there: http://www.playframework.org/modules/rythm

You can download Rythm from https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm/downloads