# Why welcome-file-list is not working if I remove struts2 .action extension?

Tags: java, struts2, action-mapping

I have a problem if I remove the `.action` extension inside my Struts2 application. I put this in my `struts.xml`:

```
<constant
    name="struts.action.extension"
    value="" />
```

The application works correctly except in the index page. I have in my `web.xml` this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

When I access to `http://localhost/myApp/`, I get the following error:

```
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and 
action name [index.jsp] associated with context path [/myApp]. 
- [unknown location]
```

However if I access to `http://localhost/myApp/fooAction`, I'm not getting any errors and works perfectly.

If I change the extension for a non empty extension (like `"html"`), I see the index page perfectly if I access to `http://localhost/myApp/`.

So then, is there something wrong in what I'm doing? Why am I getting this error when I remove extension? Is there any posible way of not getting it?

**Edit:** If I put an action in the `<welcome-page>` the error is the following:

```
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] 
associated with context path [/myApp].
```

Comment: try `<welcome-file>index</welcome-file>`

Comment: I believe S2 filter is treating it as an action.I remember i was having same issue where i want the `<welcome-file>` as my action and i removed the extension like `.jsp` from the list and created an empty file name `index`

Comment: I proved with an Action in the `<welcome-file>` before I put this here but since I read here that I can't do that directly (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399/how-can-i-set-the-welcome-page-to-a-struts-action) I didn't put here. I'm getting a different error, I will put it in the question.

Comment: @Pigueiras:This is what you all need to do ,1) create an empty file namely `index` in your web-app than you need to define a mapping in your struts file like `<action name="index" class="welcomeAction"></action>`Hope i am clear enough.One more point for putting comment please mark person name else that person will not get any notification about your comment

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Sorry, I always forget about it. Put that as an answer and I will mark it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pigueiras: I will, just curious was the suggestion helpful to some extend :)?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi No, I don't have enough knowledge for doing extends hehe =P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having same issue in one of the application where i need to call an Action on page load in place of `index.jsp` or `welcom.jsp` in `<welcome-page>`.I did the following steps

Placed the following entry in my web.xml.

```
 <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I created an empty file with name `index` in my web-app folder and finally placed the following entry in my struts.xml file

```
<action name="index" class="welcomeAction">
     <result>/ab.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

So in this case when i was hitting this URL `www.myapp.com/myApp`,its calling index action of Struts2 and i was able to do all init work for my welcome page.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue, but solved!!!!
If u use

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=""/>
```

in struts.xml 
then put welcome file as

```
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
```

in web.xml 
and give the action in struts.xml as follows

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="index.jsp">
        <result>WEB-INF/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using `websphere` run web application, need to [addtionally add struts.xml](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application#step-6---create-strutsxml), and set `<action name="">` same in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241015/websphere-struts2-not-going-to-welcome-file), then view `http://localhost:port/{context root}/` shows the `index.jsp`.

```
<package name="dst" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

    <action name="">
        <result>/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```