# Why is my struts annotation redirection not working?

Tags: java, struts2, actionresult, welcome-file

I would like to redirect to `fail.jsp` when i type my root url (`localhost:8081/`). Here is my java class Root :

```
@Namespaces(value={@Namespace("/User"), @Namespace("/")})
@Result(location="/fail.jsp")
@Actions(value={@Action(""), @Action("home")})

public class Root {

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Currently, it redirects me to `index.jsp`. Most online tutorials mention the `web.xml` but some people tells me it has nothing to do with `web.xml`. So i'm confused. May someone help me understand what i'm missing ?

Here is the tree of my app :

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do that in **that** way? Seems like a pretty harsh way to show fail on merely referring the root of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Found out i either need an `.xml` setup or a proper Spring & Struts integration to get rid of all xml.

[Here](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-struts-2-integration-tutorial-part-2-java-based-and-annotations) is the tutorial for the 2nd option

Comment: Q: *Why is my struts annotation redirection not working?* A: *get rid of all xml* - Really?

Comment: Edited. You can go easy now.

Comment: Aod, read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: web.xml **isn't** S2 specific. Spring **cannot** replace web.xml. Start by finding out what is web.xml and why do you need it, then search how and when you can replace it.

Answer (score 0):

You have `index.jsp` in the web root folder. If you requested to show this folder, and web server found that there's `index.jsp` in that folder it redirects to `index.jsp`. This code is from Tomcat's `web.xml`:

```xml
  <!-- ==================== Default Welcome File List ===================== -->
  <!-- When a request URI refers to a directory, the default servlet looks  -->
  <!-- for a "welcome file" within that directory and, if present, to the   -->
  <!-- corresponding resource URI for display.                              -->
  <!-- If no welcome files are present, the default servlet either serves a -->
  <!-- directory listing (see default servlet configuration on how to       -->
  <!-- customize) or returns a 404 status, depending on the value of the    -->
  <!-- listings setting.                                                    -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!-- If you define welcome files in your own application's web.xml        -->
  <!-- deployment descriptor, that list *replaces* the list configured      -->
  <!-- here, so be sure to include any of the default values that you wish  -->
  <!-- to use within your application.                                      -->

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

If you remove `index.jsp` from the root folder, your code might work if it has correct mapping to the action. You might also find this question [Can Struts 2 First Page come through the engine instead of listing it in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24309276/573032)  and answer useful to you.