# Comparing Strings in Struts2 <s:if> Tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have an `index.jsp` page wherein certain elements turn on/off depending on whether the user has logged in or not.

```jsp
<head>
    <s:set var="accessType" value="GUEST" />
    <s:if test="#session.containsKey('currentAccessType')">
        <s:set var="accessType" value="#session.currentAccessType" />
    </s:if>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <s:if test="#accessType.equals('GUEST')">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com" target="_blank">Main Site</a></li>
            </ul>
        </s:if>

        <s:else>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Control Panel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com" target="_blank">Main Site</a></li>
            </ul>
        </s:else>
    </nav>
</body>
```

The `accessType` is set to `GUEST`. However, it's entering the else-block even if the user has not logged in yet.

Did I commit an error in my String comparison?

**UPDATE:**
I removed the session part from the index.jsp just to see and it now looks like this:

```jsp
<head>
    <s:set var="accessType" value="GUEST" />
    <!-- removed session code for testing -->
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <s:if test="#accessType.equals('GUEST')">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com" target="_blank">Main Site</a></li>
            </ul>
        </s:if>

        <s:else>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Control Panel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com" target="_blank">Main Site</a></li>
            </ul>
        </s:else>
    </nav>

    <br />

    Access type is <s:property value="#accessType" />.
</body>
```

**Problems:**

1. Condition enters `<s:else>` block.
2. Access type is not printing (somehow not being set).

Comment: The error could be a `NullPointerException`, then you enter `s:else` tag. Show how did you put a variable into the session.

Comment: Hi @RomanC, I have edited the post for your review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing a string in the `s:if` statements and it worked good in the test file when you used a string value for the variable. So, `"'GUEST'"` worked. Without quotes OGNL is trying to parse the value in double quotes and if it can't find a variable named `GUEST` in the value stack it returns `null`. Then you tried to print this value that is converted to empty string. You have also hardcoded the value of `'GUEST'` in the JSP, it's not good.

Solution: business logic you shouldn't write in JSP. You should define the session variable in the action and access this session variable inside JSP instead of redefining a variable value based on some logical condition.

```jsp
<head>
<!--
    <s:set var="accessType" value="GUEST" />
    removed session code for testing -->
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <s:if test="#session.currentAccessType.equals('GUEST')">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.iacademy.edu.ph" target="_blank">Main Site</a></li>
            </ul>
        </s:if>

        <s:else>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Control Panel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.iacademy.edu.ph" target="_blank">Main Site</a></li>
            </ul>
        </s:else>
    </nav>

    <br />

    Access type is <s:property value="#session.currentAccessType" />.
</body>
```

Comment: I see, so `GUEST` value should come from backend. If the user is viewing the index.jsp for the first time, how would the application know he is guest? Do I need to use interceptor to set this value?

Comment: Struts in MVC framework, first you call a controller then render a view, don't call JSPs directly. In the action (controller) you define a session variable.

Comment: Hey, I've been thinking about "calling a controller". I have `index.jsp` in the `<welcome-file-list>` of my `web.xml`, so it goes to the JSP every time I run it in Eclipse. How do I call a controller?

Comment: A controller doesn't have `.jsp` at the end. And welcome files should redirect to a controller.

Comment: With the help of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399/how-can-i-set-the-welcome-page-to-a-struts-action), I have successfully called a `TestAction` Class (using a `test.jsp` with `<s:action>`) and render the `index.jsp` after. Thank you for the tip and for all your +reps yesterday, RomanC. (Edit: I updated to the "hacky" version, where you place an empty file with the same name as the action name.)

Comment: I knew about it from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12087779/573032) question, but your thread is older, I have added  struts2 tag.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the culprit.

To set String value in Struts2 var, this line:

`<s:set var="accessType" value="GUEST" />`

Should be:

`<s:set var="accessType" value="'GUEST'" />`

Single quotes (' ') must surround the String literal when placed inside the `value=""` attribute.

The if-check was correct.