# Authentication in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<s:iterator value="roleList">
    <s:if test="%{#userRole}=='Admin'}" >
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Manage Users <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="adduser.jsp">Add User</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                 <li><a href="viewusers.jsp">View / Edit User</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    </s:if>
    </s:iterator>
```

Here I want to check whether the user who has logged in is user or admin.If he/she is `user` I dont want to dsiplay one section in header section to that user which is `Manage users` but for `Admin` I want to display that block but I am unable to do so.Above is my code where `userRole` is my variable in which the role of the user is stored and `roleList` is the arraylist object in which the role value is added.So please help me or provide some links where I can study such examples and do accordingly.

Comment: `%{#userRole}=='Admin'}` Let's count. 1,2,3... something is missing or more than needed.

Comment: Besides what Aleksandr is hinting at, is `userRole` a property of the elements in `roleList` or is it the element itself?  If the latter you're missing a `var="userRole"` in the iterator tag. Additionally, why are you iterating over a list instead of checking against a set?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by referring to this 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676055/comparing-strings-in-struts2-sif-tag).It will surely help others in future .