# Call action in web.xml file in Struts 2.3

Tags: struts2

this is default implementation.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

**i want to change like below**

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.action</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

<action name="login" class="com.mm.authentication.Login">
        <result name="success">/Index.jsp</result>
```

above implementation not working.

if anyone know how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set the welcome page to a struts action?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39399/1700321)

Answer (score 0):

The welcome file is just a file. You have to rename it to something `login.jsp`. But create a new file `index.jsp` with the following content

```jsp
<% response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"login.action"); %>
```

The action configuration

```xml
<action name="login" class="com.mm.authentication.Login">
    <result name="success">/login.jsp</result>
```